# HP Usb storage Format tool : Error

Tags: windows-xp, usb, usb-flash-drive, formatting, bootable-media

I have a 2 GB Kingston Usb drive. This is working fine-  I am able to format and access from 'My computer'

I am trying to format this drive using HP USB Storage format tool to load a bootable image on to the drive,  it says "device media is write protected"

OS : Windows XP

what could be wrong ?

Thanks!

Comment: When does the error occur? Directly after starting the process or sometime in the process?

Answer (score 0):

1. Run regedit.
2. Navigate to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control.
3. Create a new key named StorageDevicePolicies.
4. Highlight StorageDevicePolicies, and then create a mew DWORD (32-bit) value named WriteProtect.
5. Double click on WriteProtect, and set its value to 1.

Comment: Tried this, It's not working...

Comment: Can you create your bootable image with another tool instead?